# How to add an argument to look up a certain keyword from the same directory

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of images to make a collage named in a certain pattern.
Ex.

- yahoo_jp.png
- yahoo_us.png
- yahoo_uk.png
- yahoo_cn.png

All files are in the same directory. Currently, I can only send a command to make a collage out of all images in a folder but what I want to do is to be able to send a certain keyword from the shell command and look up a list of files in the folder with the keywords matching and then making a collage.

Ex. shell command
make_collage.py -o my_collage.png -w 540 -i 840 new argument --> -a "_us"
- when this command is run, it will only make a collage with files containing keyword "_us" only. So the output would be a collage containing only the "_us" images.

```
import argparse
import os
import random
from PIL import Image


def make_collage(images, filename, width, init_height):
    """
    Make a collage image with a width equal to `width` from `images` and save to `filename`.
    """
    if not images:
        print('No images for collage found!')
        return False

    margin_size = 2
    # run until a suitable arrangement of images is found
    while True:
        # copy images to images_list
        images_list = images[:]
        coefs_lines = []
        images_line = []
        x = 0
        while images_list:
            # get first image and resize to `init_height`
            img_path = images_list.pop(0)
            img = Image.open(img_path)
            img.thumbnail((width, init_height))
            # when `x` will go beyond the `width`, start the next line
            if x > width:
                coefs_lines.append((float(x) / width, images_line))
                images_line = []
                x = 0
            x += img.size[0] + margin_size
            images_line.append(img_path)
        # finally add the last line with images
        coefs_lines.append((float(x) / width, images_line))

        # compact the lines, by reducing the `init_height`, if any with one or less images
        if len(coefs_lines) <= 1:
            break
        if any(map(lambda c: len(c[1]) <= 1, coefs_lines)):
            # reduce `init_height`
            init_height -= 10
        else:
            break

    # get output height
    out_height = 0
    for coef, imgs_line in coefs_lines:
        if imgs_line:
            out_height += int(init_height / coef) + margin_size
    if not out_height:
        print('Height of collage could not be 0!')
        return False

    collage_image = Image.new('RGB', (width, int(out_height)), (35, 35, 35))
    # put images to the collage
    y = 0
    for coef, imgs_line in coefs_lines:
        if imgs_line:
            x = 0
            for img_path in imgs_line:
                img = Image.open(img_path)
                # if need to enlarge an image - use `resize`, otherwise use `thumbnail`, it's faster
                k = (init_height / coef) / img.size[1]
                if k > 1:
                    img = img.resize((int(img.size[0] * k), int(img.size[1] * k)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                else:
                    img.thumbnail((int(width / coef), int(init_height / coef)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
                if collage_image:
                    collage_image.paste(img, (int(x), int(y)))
                x += img.size[0] + margin_size
            y += int(init_height / coef) + margin_size
    collage_image.save(filename)
    return True


def main():
    # prepare argument parser
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Photo collage maker')
    parse.add_argument('-f', '--folder', dest='folder', help='folder with images (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.png)', default='.')
    parse.add_argument('-o', '--output', dest='output', help='output collage image filename', default='collage.png')
    parse.add_argument('-w', '--width', dest='width', type=int, help='resulting collage image width')
    parse.add_argument('-i', '--init_height', dest='init_height', type=int, help='initial height for resize the images')
    parse.add_argument('-s', '--shuffle', action='store_true', dest='shuffle', help='enable images shuffle')

    args = parse.parse_args()
    if not args.width or not args.init_height:
        parse.print_help()
        exit(1)

    # get images
    files = [os.path.join(args.folder, fn) for fn in os.listdir(args.folder)]
    images = [fn for fn in files if os.path.splitext(fn)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')]
    if not images:
        print('No images for making collage! Please select other directory with images!')
        exit(1)

    # shuffle images if needed
    if args.shuffle:
        random.shuffle(images)

    print('Making collage...')
    res = make_collage(images, args.output, args.width, args.init_height)
    if not res:
        print('Failed to create collage!')
        exit(1)
    print('Collage is ready!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `glob.glob()` along with `os.listdir()`, although `glob()` uses bash syntax so you'll need to enter `*_us*`.

First import it:

```
from glob import glob
```

Then add a "pattern" optional positional arg:

```
parse.add_argument('-p', '--pattern', nargs="?", default=None, help="enter a grep-like expansion.")
```

Finally, change the line under `# get images` to something like this:

```
if args.pattern:
    files = [fn for fn in glob(os.path.join(args.folder, args.pattern))]
else:
    files = [os.path.join(args.folder, fn) for fn in os.listdir(args.folder)]
```

Comment: Hi Rob, I’m getting a syntax error on the last bracket “...args.pattern)]” this one is highlighted when running —> ]

Comment: oops! forgot to close out `glob()` Will fix.

Comment: Also note that I removed the first `os.path.join()` in the top list comprehension. `glob()` gives back full absolute paths by default.

Comment: Hi Rob,this time I have an error saying  " 'module' object has no attribute 'join' and the error is pointing to this row -> "files = [fn for fn in glob(os.join(args.folder, args.pattern))]"

Comment: Hi Rob, I was able to fix the issue after changing line `files = [fn for fn in glob(os.join(args.folder, args.pattern))]` to `files = [fn for fn in glob(os.path.join(args.folder, args.pattern))]`

Comment: Hi Ron, really sorry for being a noob here. Is there a button where I can give the credit that you helped?

Comment: Lol you did it! My apologies for the sloppy response!